# Run/Debug Configurations not working for renamed Cordova commands in WebStorm

Tags: cordova, webstorm, ionic3, run-configuration

I'm under **Windows 10** and I've installed the browser platform for **Cordova** for my **Ionic app**.

```
ionic cordova platform add browser
```

Now I'd like to have a **Run Configuration** for the following command.

```
ionic cordova run browser --target=Firefox
```

Adding a new configuration of type **PhoneGap/Cordova** to **WebStorm** with the desired parameters yields this message:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2017.1.4\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic.cmd run browser
    The run command has been renamed. To find out more, run:

      ionic cordova run --help
```

Apparently WebStorm is using older commands.

Is there a workaround or a plugin fixing this? Or can you make a custom run configuration where you only execute a command in the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ionic 3 cli is not currently supported, and unfortunately there is no way to change the command - it's hardcoded:( Please follow (WEB-27402)[https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27402] for updates.

You can integrate cli as external tool, or use BashSupport plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4230-bashsupport) that supports generic run configurations that can be used to run any CLI tool

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by saving the %APPDATA%\npm\ionic.cmd to ionic3.cmd and modifying the existing ionic.cmd to rewrite ionic 2 commands to be ionic 3 commands. Code below:

```
@echo off

IF "%1" == "build" GOTO cordova
IF "%1" == "compile" GOTO cordova
IF "%1" == "emulate" GOTO cordova
IF "%1" == "platform" GOTO cordova
IF "%1" == "plugin" GOTO cordova
IF "%1" == "prepare" GOTO cordova
IF "%1" == "resources" GOTO cordova
IF "%1" == "run" GOTO cordova
GOTO ionic

:ionic
IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic" %*
) ELSE (
  SETLOCAL
  SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic" %*
)
GOTO end

:cordova
IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic" cordova %*
) ELSE (
  SETLOCAL
  SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic" cordova %*
)
GOTO end

:end
```

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for the ionic3 support, you can try to create a 
%APPDATA%\npm\ionic3.cmd 
with the content
%APPDATA%\npm\ionic.cmd cordova %*
In the WebStorm Run/Debug configuration call the ionic3.cmd
It worked for me
Regards